# where is "admin/url/custom" path in magento site database file

Tags: admin, database, sql

i am following this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202950/magento-admin-url-not-working-404-after-changing-it-cant-go-back

in core_config_data, i want to know where is this path : admin/url/custom admin/url/custom_path

means usually in which page these path will be available ?

in core_config_data , there are 55 pages with 30 rows each,

i want to know in which page these paths i can find : admin/url/custom admin/url/custom_path
?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_ScopeHint to show the path in `core_config_data` next to each configuration value. It also highlights website and store specific changes. This is one of the few extensions that I install in every shop that I work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pages you are talking about are specific to PHPMyAdmin, to help user have a more understandable interface, by only showing a specific number of rows. So it doesn't really matter which page they are, and it would change from a project to another.

What you need to do is look for the path you want with a SQL query (or with a search if you are using phpmyadmin or a similar tool).

You could use this request :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%admin/url/%";
```

This will select all the rows where the path contains "admin/url/", then you should be able to modify them.

If you are using phpmyadmin, you can go to the sql section and execute this command, or go to the search section, and search for the path you want to find.

Answer (score 3):

If this query `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%admin/url/%";` returned you zero results, Look for your local.xml config **app/etc/local.xml** and try finding for admin node and frontname.

That was it in my case, hopefully it helps somebody. Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

Answering directly on your question:

If you do not find some value in `core_config_data` it means only one: if you never saved this value from `system / configuration` - there will be no such value in database.

In other words: After clean magento installation your `core_config_data` table contains only 10-20 lines. If you save any configuration - these values will appear in database. Try to open `system / configuration / admin` (don't forget select necessary store view) - then press save. After that you will find in this table what you are looking for. You also can configure it from admin area.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Magento admin url in

```
/app/etc/local.xml
```

Find this in your xml file. Here

> storeadmin
>   is my admin url

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[storeadmin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```